# Data Structure and algorithm for Interlacing "Task Lists"

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, linked-list, graph-theory

I need some advice if there already exists some well known data structure and algorithm to achieve the following example outlined below. Due to a lack of CS vocabularym I can only summarize it as "Interlacing Task Lists"

Let's say you have 2+ more tasks separated into n_1 steps. You know the duration of the task and the time between those tasks (min time, max time). I want to find the shortest time to combine those tasks and minimize with respect to time.

Here is a simple example:

```
Cooking Rice: (Duration: 24.5 minutes)
Wash Rice (3 min) -> Season Rice & Add water (0.5 min) -> Bring Rice to a Boil (4 min) -> Let Rice cook (10 min) -> Let Rice steam (5 min) -> Serve Rice (2 min) -> Ready
```

```
Steaming Broccoli: (Duration: 17 minutes)
Wash Broccoli (0.5 min) -> Cut Broccoli (1 min) -> Bring to a Boil (4 min) -> Steam (11 min) -> Serve Broccoli -> Ready.
```

There are multiple ways to parallelise those two "Task-Chains". However there are boundary conditions and the nodes can be stretched out.
For example I can wash the rice and add water and season it and then let it sit for 10-20 minutes while preparing the Broccoli.
I want to optimize with respect to time.

For only these two tasks, the result could be:

```
Wash Rice (3 min) -> Season Rice & Add water (3.5 min) -> Bring Rice to a Boil (7.5 min) -> Wash Broccoli (8 min) -> Cut Broccoli (9 min) -> Bring Broccoli to a Boil (13 min) -> Switch Broccoli to Steam (17) -> Turn off Rice (17.5 min) -> Serve Rice (22.5 min) -> Serve Broccoli (24.5 min) -> Ready (26 min)
```

Obviously, I want to parallelize multiple task not just two.

After seeing seemingly similar posts, the difference here is the order of the tasks in on list must stay intact and the tasks of the other lists must be done while processes of the already stated list is on pause.

I kind of assume this problem has been solved a million times and I just don't know what to look for. I tried to look into multi-threading but could not fine a resource except for high-level tips on how to use threads.

I would be very happy if somebody can give me a few pointers what to read into.

Comment: In your example, serve brocoli has no duration. In your result, it has 24.5 mins

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to focus on the steps.

Each step has a duration and a pointer to another step that must be completed before it can start.

There are various ways to solve this.  The easiest way to get a feasible solution is to maintain a list of steps that are ready to start ( the task they depend on has been completed ). When the step processor ( or processors ) completes a step, it finds step(s) that now become ready, adding them to the list and then choosing one step from the list to start.

This is quick and easy to code in your favorite language.  Once you have that working and debugged, you will have a good feeling for the intricacies and can choose from the various optimization algorithms you'll find by googling.

The traditional way to do this is called the Critical Path Method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method

Getting technical now. Finding the critical path:

- Model the entire project as a graph in the form of a tree.
- Add a start node.  This is the root of the tree.  Make every step that is not dependent om any other, the child of the root node.
- Complete the tree by adding dependent steps as children of the steps they depend on.  The link between parent and child nodes as cost equal to the child step's duration.
- Use depth first search algorithm to find the leaf node that is most expensive to reach from the root.
- The path from the root to the most expensive leaf is the Critical Path.

When the step processor completes a step, choose from the ready list the step that is on the Critical Path.  If no ready task is on the Critical Path, choose the ready task that has the smallest float ( the delay that would cause the step to become part of the critical path )

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, I really appreciate it.
I'll need a moment to digest the information and will try to write a proof on concept.

Comment: "Model the entire project as a graph in the form of a tree"
That's pretty much the task I want to automate.

Comment: I get the gist to create a tree with with all possible combinations and then do 
the DFS to find the best possible way. That helps a lot.

Comment: What I'll have to think about is how to formulate my problem with dependencies.
Up until now my tasks are not dependent on each other. I only have one person 
cooking (one processor).

Comment: To repeat, focus on the steps, not the tasks. A step is dependent on the previous step in the task.

Comment: Construct each step as you read the input data, with the duration and steps that need to be completed before it starts.   Details depend on the input format.  I use the Standard Task Graph format http://www.kasahara.cs.waseda.ac.jp/schedule/format_e.html

Comment: "I only have one person cooking (one processor)."  Are you sure?  Can you not steam the rice in one pot and, at the same time, steam the broccoli in another pot?  Perhaps you should set the number of processors to be the number of burners on your stove.  Or more accurately, specify the resources each step requires and the available resources, perhaps two pots and one chopping knife?